# Flutter null safety on class constructors

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and using the latest version of it.
Null safety keeps bothering me. I tried my best to solve this problem on the internet but couldn't figure out.

I've tried changing 'navi' type but the still getting this error on the line 'onPressed: navi'.

> "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'"

```
class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  late Color? color;
  late String? text;
  late Function navi;

  RoundedButton({super.key, this.color, this.text, required this.navi});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        color: color!,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: navi,
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          child: Text(text!),
          // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//Using class in the build method looks like this
RoundedButton(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              text: 'Log In',
              navi: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
              },
            )
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VoidCallback` which is same as void function.

```dart
  late VoidCallback navi;
```

And instead of late, you can make it final

```dart
class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color? color;
  final String? text;
  final VoidCallback navi;

 const  RoundedButton({super.key, this.color, this.text, required this.navi});
```

Comment: Oh, it was a simple problem. Thank you so much, Yeasin.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [VoidCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html) and [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

The error does not come from the null-safety though. It should be `Function() navi;` instead of `Function`.

`late` keyword suggests that the variable has delayed initialization, check [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables) for reference.